# Strange Rails resource routes behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've met strange error. Im not sure this is bug. However i never met this strange behavior before.

```
resource :watches
```

Makes such strange routing table:

```
        watches POST   /watches(.:format)                         watches#create
    new_watches GET    /watches/new(.:format)                     watches#new
   edit_watches GET    /watches/edit(.:format)                    watches#edit
                GET    /watches(.:format)                         watches#show
                PUT    /watches(.:format)                         watches#update
                DELETE /watches(.:format)                         watches#destroy
```

As you see **no ID param and messed actions**

On same time:

```
resources :mibs
```

Make proper routes

```
           mibs GET    /mibs(.:format)                            mibs#index
                POST   /mibs(.:format)                            mibs#create
        new_mib GET    /mibs/new(.:format)                        mibs#new
       edit_mib GET    /mibs/:id/edit(.:format)                   mibs#edit
            mib GET    /mibs/:id(.:format)                        mibs#show
                PUT    /mibs/:id(.:format)                        mibs#update
                DELETE /mibs/:id(.:format)                        mibs#destroy
```

I thought that is could be somehow inflector problem, but trying using "rockets" instead of "watches" give same result:

```
        rockets POST   /rockets(.:format)                         rockets#create
    new_rockets GET    /rockets/new(.:format)                     rockets#new
   edit_rockets GET    /rockets/edit(.:format)                    rockets#edit
                GET    /rockets(.:format)                         rockets#show
                PUT    /rockets(.:format)                         rockets#update
                DELETE /rockets(.:format)                         rockets#destroy
```

Anything except my first two resources (servers and mibs) make such result.

Probably corrupted routing cache somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resource` indicates a singleton resource: in other words, you're telling Rails that there's only ever one watch for each user, so passing IDs would be useless.

`resources` is the standard invocation for getting routes with IDs attached.

So, essentially, the problem is an inflector one, but for `resource` or `resources`, not for the name of your routes. For more information, check out the [Ruby on Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It does a good job explaining the difference between singleton resources and the more usual kind.

Comment: Thank you. Just found anwser myself. I should sleep more :)

Comment: No problem, easy thing to miss!